# Unclear how a yacc/bison production spec can cause a stack overflow

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

This is not homework, but it is from a book. I'm given the following grammar:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int yylex();
int yyerror();
%}

%%

command : exp '\n' { printf("%d\n", $1); exit(0); }
        | error '\n'
          { 
            yyerrok;
            printf("reenter expression: "); 
          }
          command
        ;

exp : exp '+' term { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | exp '-' term { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    | term { $$ = $1; }
    ;

term : term '*' factor { $$ = $1 * $3; }
     | factor { $$ = $1; }
     ;

factor : NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
       | '(' exp ')' { $$ = $2; }
       ;

%%

int main() {
  return yyparse();
}

int yylex() {
  int c;

  /* eliminate blanks*/
  while((c = getchar()) == ' ');

  if (isdigit(c)) {
    ungetc(c, stdin);
    scanf("%d\n", &yylval);
    return (NUMBER);
  }

  /* makes the parse stop */
  if (c == '\n') return 0;

  return (c);
}

int yyerror(char * s) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
  return 0;
} /* allows for printing of an error message */
```

Here is the task:

> The simple error recovery technique suggested for the calculator program is flawed in that it
>   could cause stack overflow after many errors. Rewrite it to remove
>   this problem.

I can't really figure out how a stack overflow can occur. Given the starting production is the only one that has an error token in it, wouldn't yacc/bison pop all the elements on the stack and before restarting?

Comment: Hint: right recursion vs left recursion, impact on parser stack..

Comment: After an error in `command`, `command` is then called recursively, which would eventually lead to stack overflow after a _very_, _very_ long time, if the user persisted with throwing erroneous expressions at the parser.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Isn't the Bison/Yacc work that it will keep popping symbols off the stack until an error production is reached. Given that this is a start production, wouldn't it be empty by the time a new command is entered?

Comment: I'm probably out of my depth here - I'll refer to @rici and delete my comment soon.

Comment: @flashburn: This isn't the real start production. The augmented grammar contains a production like `$start: command $eof` But that really isn't the point. The point is that an error production is just like any other production, once error recovery is underway. So suppose you had a production `command: NUMBER '\n' | NUMBER '\n' command`

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: By the way, bison produces bottom-up parsers, not recursive descent parsers. `command` is not "called". However, a parser state is pushed onto the parser stack prior to shifting any token onto the stack; the state and token are not popped until some production is completed. Consequently, right recursion causes the stack to keep growing until the outermost instance of the recursive production is reduced.

Comment: @rici: Yup, I was right - out of my depth :) - Thanks for lesson.

Comment: @rici I'm not sure I understand. Here is the rule that I have for error recovery *When the parser detects an error during parse, it pops states from the parsing stack until it reaches a state with the `error` pseudotoken is a legal lookachead. The effect is to discard input to the left of the error, and to view the input as containing the `error` pseudotoken.* Given this rule, wouldn't it keep popping the stack until it is empty for this specific case? What am I missing?

Comment: @flashburn: It pops states until it finds a state which accepts an `error` token. Any itemset which includes `comment: . error '\n' {MRA} comment` qualifies, regardless of where it is on the stack. So it will pop only until it reaches the topmost such state.

Comment: @rici I'm still missing something. Given that `command` rule is the top most rule, how come the stack will overflow if everything has just been popped?

Comment: "that" command rule? Which command rule?

Comment: @rici This is the rule I'm talking about `command : exp '\n' { printf("%d\n", $1); exit(0); }
        | error '\n'
          { 
            yyerrok;
            printf("reenter expression: "); 
          }
          command
        ;`

Comment: @flashburn: yes, I know which rule you're talking about, but my point is that you haven't identified which instance of that rule. See the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, the simplest thing is to use bison.

I modified the program slightly in order to avoid the bugs. First, since the new program relies on seeing `'\n'` tokens, I removed the line `if (c == '\n') return 0;` which would suppress sending `'\n'`. Second, I fixed `scanf("%d\n", &yylval);` to `scanf("%d", &yylval);`. There's no reason to swallow the whitespace following the number, *particularly* if the whitespace following the number is a newline. (However, `scanf` patterns don't distinguish between different kinds of whitespace, so the pattern `"%d\n"` has exactly the same semantics as `"%d "`. Neither of those would be correct.)

Then I added the line `yydebug = 1;` at the top of `main` and supplied the `-t` ("trace") option to bison when I built the calculator. That causes the parser to show its progress in detail as it processes the input.

It helps to get a state table dump in order to see what's going on. You can do that with the `-v` bison option. I'll leave that for readers, though.

Then I ran the program and deliberately typed an syntax error:

```
./error
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: 2++3
```

The trace facility has already output two lines, but after I give it some input, the trace comes pouring out.

First, the parser absorbs the NUMBER `2` and the operator `+`: (Note: `nterm` below is bison's way of saying "non-terminal", while `token` is a "terminal"; the stack shows only state numbers.)

```
Next token is token NUMBER ()
Shifting token NUMBER ()
Entering state 2
Reducing stack by rule 9 (line 25):
   $1 = token NUMBER ()
-> $$ = nterm factor ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 7
Reducing stack by rule 8 (line 22):
   $1 = nterm factor ()
-> $$ = nterm term ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 6
Reading a token: Next token is token '+' ()
Reducing stack by rule 6 (line 18):
   $1 = nterm term ()
-> $$ = nterm exp ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 5
Next token is token '+' ()
Shifting token '+' ()
Entering state 12
```

So far, so good. State 12 is where we get to after we've seen `+`; here is its definition:

```
State 12

    4 exp: exp '+' . term
    7 term: . term '*' factor
    8     | . factor
    9 factor: . NUMBER
   10       | . '(' exp ')'

    NUMBER  shift, and go to state 2
    '('     shift, and go to state 3

    term    go to state 17
    factor  go to state 7
```

(By default, bison doesn't clutter up the state table with non-core items. I added `-r itemset` to get the full itemset, but it would have been easy enough to do the closure by hand.)

Since in this state we're looking for the right-hand operand of `+`, only things which can start an expression are valid: NUMBER and `(`. But that's not what we've got:

```
Reading a token: Next token is token '+' ()
syntax error
```

OK, we're in State 12, and if you look at the above state description, you'll see that `error` is not in the lookahead set either. So:

```
Error: popping token '+' ()
Stack now 0 5
```

That puts us back in State 5, which is where an operator was expected:

```
State 5

    1 command: exp . '\n'
    4 exp: exp . '+' term
    5    | exp . '-' term

    '\n'  shift, and go to state 11
    '+'   shift, and go to state 12
    '-'   shift, and go to state 13
```

So that state doesn't have a transition on `error` either. Onwards.

```
Error: popping nterm exp ()
Stack now 0
```

OK, back to the beginning. State 0 *does* have an `error` transition:

```
   error   shift, and go to state 1
```

So now we can shift the `error` token and enter state 1, as indicated by the transition table:

```
Shifting token error ()
Entering state 1
```

Now we need to synchronize the input by skipping input tokens until we get to a newline token. (Note that bison actually pops and pushes the error token while it's doing this. Try not to let that distract you.)

```
Next token is token '+' ()
Error: discarding token '+' ()
Error: popping token error ()
Stack now 0
Shifting token error ()
Entering state 1
Reading a token: Next token is token NUMBER ()
Error: discarding token NUMBER ()
Error: popping token error ()
Stack now 0
Shifting token error ()
Entering state 1
Reading a token: Next token is token '\n' ()
Shifting token '\n' ()
Entering state 8
```

Right, we found the newline. State 5 is `command: error '\n' . $@1 command`. `$@1` is the name of the marker (empty production) which bison inserted in place of the mid-rule action (MRA). State 8 will reduce this marker, causing the MRA to run, which asks me for more input. Note that at this point error recovery is complete. We are now in a perfectly normal state, and the stack reflects the fact that we have, in order, the start (state 0), an `error` token (state 1) and a newline token (state 8):

```
Reducing stack by rule 2 (line 13):
-> $$ = nterm $@1 ()
Stack now 0 1 8
Entering state 15
Reading a token: Try again:
```

After the MRA is reduced, the corresponding action from State 8 is taken and we proceed to State 15 (to avoid clutter, I left out the non-core items):

```
State 15

    3 command: error '\n' $@1 . command

    error   shift, and go to state 1
    NUMBER  shift, and go to state 2
    '('     shift, and go to state 3
```

So now we're ready to parse a brand new command, as expected. But we have not yet reduced the error production; it's still on the stack because it can't be reduced until the `command` following the dot has been reduced. And we haven't even started on it yet.

But it's important to note that State 15 *does* have a transition on `error`, as you can see from the state's goto table. It has that transition because the closure includes the two productions for `command`:

```
    1 command: . exp '\n'
    3        | . error '\n' $@1 command
```

as well as the productions for `exp`, `term` and `factor`, which are also part of the closure.

So what happens if we now enter another error? The stack will be popped back to this point (`0 1 8 15`), a new `error` token will be pushed onto the stack (`0 1 8 15 1`), tokens will be discarded until a newline can be shifted (`0 1 8 15 1 8`) and a new MRA (`$@1`, as bison calls it) will be reduced onto the stack (`0 1 8 15 1 8 15`) at which point we're ready to start parsing yet another attempt.

Hopefully you can see where this is going.

Note that it really is not different from the effect of any other right-recursive production. Had the grammar attempted to accept a number of expressions:

```
prog: exp '\n'
    | exp '\n' { printf("%d\n", $1); } prog
```

you would see the same stack build-up, which is why right-recursion is discouraged. (And also because you end up inserting MRAs to avoid seeing the results in reverse order as the stack is reduced down to `prog` at the end of all input.)

```
    command  go to state 20
    exp      go to state 5
    term     go to state 6
    factor   go to state 7
```

Comment: Really nice explanation!

Comment: @rici Just out of curiosity, why does `bison` pop the `error` token when it discards an input token. I also can't figure out the meaning of parentheses in the tracked output. Sometimes it says `Reading a token: Next token is token NUMBER ()`, sometimes `Reducing stack by rule 8 (line 28):`. I can't really figure out why some of the parentheses are empty and some have values in them?

Comment: @rici Another question. I notices that State 15 has the following closure
`1 command: . exp '\n' 
    3        | . error '\n' $@1 command
    3        | error '\n' $@1 . command`

There seems to be two rules marked with a 3, is that an error?

Comment: `line 28` isn't a value; it is the line in your source code where the relevant production is found. The parentheses in the token reading message surround the semantic value of the token read, if you have defined an appropriate print method. (Bison doesn't know how to print semantic values unless you tell it.) Try adding the bison declaration `%printer { fprintf(yyoutput, "%d", $$); } NUMBER` if you want to see values between the parentheses.

Comment: @flashburn: No, those are the same rule with the dot in different places. The 3 refers to the list of rules at the beginning of the output file.

Comment: @rici I've been at it, trying to figure out how to overcome the stack overflow problem, and the only way I could think of is to remove the `error` production. But I'm pretty sure that this is not what the author of the question wanted. Do you mind giving any other suggestions? What if I want to empty the stack completely and ask for the user to renter the expression, how would I do it?

Comment: @flashburn: The `error` production is not the problem. See my very first comment (to your question).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113172/discussion-between-flashburn-and-rici).